# Time Difference when user is late, tracking

Tags: java, android

I want to calculate the difference in minutes between two dates, if this difference is > 0 and < 50 minutes, I show a textview with the next text: "X until limit time" (it's on time, but is close to the limit)
If the difference is < 0 (it's late) the textview should say "X minutes late"

Right now everything work for the first condition, but for the second one, the number sometimes show 740 minutes late or bigger numbers

```
Date fechaactual = new Date();
long diff = trackingfecha.getTime() - fechaactual.getTime();
long diferenciaminutos = diff / (60 * 1000);
RunneableUpdateUI run = new RunneableUpdateUI();
if(diferenciaminutos < 50) {
    if(diferenciaminutos >= 0) {
        //Show the minutes close to some specific time
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append("te quedan ");
        String minutes = String.format("%02d", diferenciaminutos);
        buffer.append(minutes);
        buffer.append(" min");
        run.toUpdateValue = buffer.toString();
    } else {
       //Here is the problem
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String minutes = String.format("%02d", Math.abs(diferenciaminutos));
        buffer.append(minutes);
        buffer.append(" min tarde");
        run.toUpdateValue = buffer.toString();
    }
    timerHandler.post(run);
}
```

Comment: Why it can't be 740 minutes late?

Comment: This happens when the user is late just for a couple hours no almost 12 hours

Answer (score -1):

```
if (0<=x && x < 50)
        {
            // x time to reach
        }
        else
        {
            if (0> x)
            {
                // late
             }
         }

    }
```

where x  is your Time Diffrent